# Set height to the lowest height of the sibling child div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have multiple rows, every row has multiple columns, in each column i have a div + a paragraphe, the div includes an image. i need to set the div with the class **cover-bg** to the lowest height of **cover-bg** in the same **row** the calculated height of the **cover-bg** in the first **row** can't be the same height in the second **row**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="cover-bg"><img src="url"></div>
        <p>text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="cover-bg"><img src="url"></div>
        <p>text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="cover-bg"><img src="url"></div>
        <p>text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="cover-bg"><img src="url"></div>
        <p>text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this but it sets the lowest height of all the rows :

```
var minHeight = Math.min.apply(null, $('.cover-bg').map(function(){return $(this).height()}));
$('.cover-bg').height(minHeight);
```

I am having trouble manipulating the siblings() and children()

The problem is how to separate and set the height for each row

[image]

Comment: Im a little confused by your question. Could you try and rephrase or it even better show an image of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @RichardHpa i've added an image to make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set an image height for each row otherwise all will have the same height.

I got a bit confused with the suggested jquery so here is a snippet which spells it out in pure JS.

For each row it finds the minimum image height and then sets a CSS variable property of that row to that height. This is used to style each of the images in that particular row.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    .row {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    .row .cover-bg img:first-child {
      height: calc(var(--h) * 1px);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="cover-bg"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/500"></div>
      <p>
        weofijae
        <br/> weofjiawef awoeifj awoefij

      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="cover-bg"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/200/1000"></div>
      <p>text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="cover-bg"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300"></div>
      <p>text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="cover-bg"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/200/200"></div>
      <p>text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    function start() {
      const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row');
      rows.forEach(row => {
        const imgs = row.querySelectorAll('img');
        let heights = [];
        imgs.forEach(img => {
          heights.push(img.height);
        });
        row.style.setProperty('--h', Math.min.apply(null, heights));
      });
    }
    window.onload = start;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: you need to wait til the images are loaded before getting their natural heights.

Run the snippet full page otherwise the rows may wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var minHeight = Math.min(...$.map($('.cover-bg'), (e) => ($(e).height())));
$('.cover-bg').height(minHeight);
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/guswnsxodlf/pen/KKXxzaM) is the example.